# Install Grammalecte for French to Libre writer

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice

Ubuntu 20.04 Libreoffice Version: 6.4.6.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

I had been using Grammaecte on a laptop but recently changed to a NUC and so I did a fresh install of libreoffice.

Grammalecte showed in the top tool bar, and the drop down menu appears on a right click, however nothing happens with any selection from this menu.I tried to check it was installed using the extension manager but it had no entries/extensions. I tried to "ADD" the extension but received the dialogue message:-

"*my home folder* /.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/-uno_packages/lu3872hd6nli.tmp_/Grammalecte-fr-v1.12.2.oxt does not exist".

I deleted the original download and downloaded a "new" copy, but the same happened. However the latest version I download is Grammalecte-fr-v2.1.1.oxt. which as you can see is different from the dialogue message.

Checking the folder with 'ls' on a terminal  .../cache/-uno_packages shows 3 entries:-

registry

uno_packages

uno_packages.pmap

the uno_packages folder is empty and a 'cat' on the the uno_packages.pmap shows:-
*Pmp1�French.linguistic.resources.from.Dicollecte.by.OlivierR
lu3872hd6nli.tmp�Grammalecte-fr-v1.12.2.oxt�application/vnd.sun.star.package-bundle�7.3�0*

Previously on a laptop, following the Extension Manager instructions I was able to load and run the extension without any problems.

I rely upon this extension as my French grammar is not always correct. This is about all I am capable of doing as I've reached the limit of my knowledge of things I can try I'd really appreciate any help.
Hal_v

Comment: Current version of LO is v 7.0.4.2. Where did you re-install LO from?

Comment: Thank you 24601, I missed your question before entering my solution, as I said I used the Snap version which is as you say 7.0.4.2 Hal_v

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by removing Libreoffice, then re-installing (I used the Snap version), then I was able to add Grammalecte as an extension which is now working.

If you have spent time looking to resolve this for me I thank you most sincerely.
Hal_v